# How do I specify a custom formatter in spec_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on a Rails project with Rspec tests that take very long to run. In order to figure out which ones are taking so much time I figured I'd make a custom formatter for RSpec and have it print out the duration of each example:

```
require 'rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter'

class TimestampFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::BaseFormatter

  def initialize(output)
    super(output)
    @last_start = 0
  end

  def example_started(example)
    super(example)
    output.print "Example started: " << example.description
    @last_start = Time.new
  end

  def example_passed(example)
    super(example)
    output.print "Example finished"
    now = Time.new
    time_diff = now - @last_start

    hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.day_fraction_to_time(time_diff)
    output.print "Time elapsed: #{hours} hours, #{minutes} minutes and #{seconds} seconds"    
  end
end
```

And in my spec_helper.rb I tried the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|      
  config.formatter = :timestamp
end
```

But I end up getting the following error when running rspec:

```
configuration.rb:217:in `formatter=': Formatter 'timestamp' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)
```

How do I make my custom formatter available as a symbol?

Answer (score 4):

```
config.formatter = :timestamp
```

This is wrong. For custom formatters you need to specify full class name, in your case

```
# if you load it manually
config.formatter = TimestampFormatter
# or if you do not want to autoload it by rspec means, but it should be in
# search path
config.formatter = 'TimestampFormatter'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the answer but, you know you can run RSpec with the --profile flag to do just that, right ? :)

Comment: It's all being kicked off on our CI server via a Rake task that runs RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:our_spec), so I figured the configuration was the best place to set the formatter.

Comment: well you can edit your project .rspec file and add the --profile flag inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the formatter to your spec directory and run the rspec command as following:

```
rspec spec/ -f TimestampFormatter
```